# Bottom div to occupy remaining space with vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```css
.ListContainer {
     overflow-y: scroll;
     height: 500px;
    }
```

```html
    <h1>Some header</h1>
    <div>Some panel</div>
    <div class="ListContainer">ui-office-fabric grid here</div>
```

I need to have ListContainer div to occupy the rest of the vertical space until the bottom, so scrolling inside that div will reveal hidden items.
Fixed height is no good because monitors have different resolutions. So with higher resolution there will be a blank space below the div.

I tried specifying height: calc(100% - 240px) but it has no effect.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you mean?

```
height: calc(100vh - 240px);
```

Comment: height: calc(100vh - 240px) didn't help. Now height in calculated css properties (in Chrome's dev tools) shows ~ 2200px. Div doesn't restrict content to remaining html page though. Instead, browser's vertical scrollbar appears.

Answer (score 0):

You need a container that has the height you need, in this case 100vh. And then, you can use flexbox, and make sure your list container grows as needed.

```css
.main {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red; /** This is just for testing **/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ListContainer {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   border: 1px solid black; /** This is just for testing **/
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1>Some header</h1>
  <div>Some panel</div>
  <div class="ListContainer">
    ui-office-fabric grid here<br>
    ui-office-fabric grid here<br>
    ui-office-fabric grid here<br>
    ui-office-fabric grid here<br>
    ui-office-fabric grid here<br>
    ui-office-fabric grid here<br>
    ui-office-fabric grid here<br>
    ui-office-fabric grid here<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks much closer now, thanks. I simplified layout. Actually I have much more at the top. If I restrict .main to height: 70vh, it fits ok on 27" monitor, but on 21" monitor I get a bit of a browser scroll.

Comment: It appears that top content I'd like to "skip" is 300px. But height: calc(100% - 300px) somehow doesn't calculate remaining space.

Comment: If you can replicate the problem in a fiddle or codepen, I can take a look :)